# Java Request.isRequestedSessionValid() still true after session expires

Tags: java, session, security

I am using Spring Security 3.0 and created a custom filter to check for expired sessions.

My problem is that request.isRequestedSessionValid() returns true in my filter even after I let the session expire or log out. If I try to access any secured page, I do get redirected to my login page so I know that the session management works.

My understanding was that when a web session times out, the session is automatically invalidated and I also set invalidate-session in my logout element of Spring Security. How can the session still be valid? Am I checking the wrong value?

Comment: I'm not sure if that call will create a session if there isn't one. Try `request.getSession(false)`. If that returns null then your other call is creating a sesssion, so use this instead to check.

Comment: Looks like you were right, using request.getSession(false) fixed it for me. Add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.isRequestedSessionValid()` can itself cause a session to be created, even after logout has been called. Use `request.getSession(false) != null` to check instead, which will ensure that a session is not created.